# TFS vNext build - Cannot get check-in numbers which are checked in by the build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfvc

I have a usecase where I need to decide which changeset(s) are checked-in by a corresponding vNext build in TFS2019.

We used to have a working associated changes area in XAML, which only showed what has been checked in that case.

In terms of vNext it seems that area shows each changesets in associated changes in between successfull builds (or at most 50), independent if that is checked-in by the build or not.

The strange thing is that its even show changes which are completely unrelated to the build (change is not included) because if the source version of the build is C113 then there are changes during the build run like, C114, C115 and the build checks in the C116 the associated changes will contains C114,C115 and C116 as well. From my point of view it doesnt make any sense.

Do you know how can I check via API if C114,C115 or C116 checked-in by the build itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changesets?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1&tabs=HTTP) and then filter in your query with `searchCriteria.fromId` and `searchCriteria.toId`.